How do I ensure selected html li element is within visible window
In the html below I am building a list of items and one of these was selected by the user.
<ul id="test">
       @foreach (var item in (ViewBag.Shapes as List<Models.ItemsModel>).OrderBy(_ => _.Ndx))
       {
           @if (ViewBag.Selected == @item.Ndx)
           {
               <li class="clr-b is-selected">
                   <a name="selectit" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="BattleShapes" asp-route-id="@item.Ndx">@item.Name</a>
               </li>
           }
           else
           {
               <li class="clr-a">
                   <a name="selectit" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="BattleShapes" asp-route-id="@item.Ndx">@item.Name</a>
               </li>
           }
       }
    </ul>

Now one of the items was selected by the user and this is correctly picked up with the code
@if (ViewBag.Selected == @item.Ndx)

However the list can be over 60 items long and the selected item is often not in the visible window, is there a way for forcing the selected li element to near the top of the visible window?

That's not (just) HTML. Add the appropriate tags please
